# Properties of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am struggeling with an easy deduction that I cannot see for some reason today myself, hope to get some help on this:
Suppose $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then I understand that $(Tx,x)$ is always real, how can I deduce from this that for $\lambda \in \mathcal{C}$

\begin{equation}
|((T-\lambda)x,x)| \leq |\text{Im}(\lambda)||x|^2
\end{equation}

Many thanks !!

Comment: Probably that inequality should go in the opposite direction. The good answer below addresses the correct direction of inequality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
((T-\lambda)x,x) &= (Tx,x)-(\lambda x, x) \\
&= (Tx,x)- \bar \lambda |x|^2\\
&= (Tx,x)-\text{Re}(\lambda)|x|^2+ i\text{ Im}(\lambda)|x|^2
\end{align}
The imaginary part of $((T-\lambda)x,x)$ is $\text{Im}(\lambda) |x|^2$. Hence, $|((T-\lambda)x,x)|$ must be at least $|\text{Im}(\lambda)| |x|^2$.